# Activity stops working when I use function of database in it

Tags: android, database

I have a second activity and I try to use a function of my database activity but for some reason I got an error.

Anything wrong with this function?

```
public void addNote(String title, String content){

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("title", title);
        cv.put("content", content);
        db.insertOrThrow("Notes", null, cv);

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
    finally {
         if(db.isOpen())
              db.close();
    }
}
```

loc cat:

```
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): Process: com.naamad.privategallery, PID: 1549
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.naamad.privategallery.DBHandler.addUser(DBHandler.java:28)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.naamad.privategallery.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:60)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-13 13:30:35.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Error in addUser function,what is RegisterActivity.java:60 ? post RegisterActivity code.

Comment: Unrelated, you're eating your sqlexception.  e.getCause() does nothing.  Replace with 'new RuntimeException(e)'.  That will cause your app to crash if there's a SQLiteException, but that's a good thing.  Right now, you'll have no idea if something is wrong.